# Firepad's color button does not change color of the text

Tags: firepad

I am using the userlist.html given in github. However the color drop down does not change the color of the text. Everything else works as expected. I also do not get any error in the console.

PS: I am using codemirror with firepad.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because of the codemirror mode which was set to Javascript. Hence it was trying to use javascript's coloring scheme.

Comment: [Firebase Community Manager here] I encourage you to join our Firepad Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firepad-io You can use it to ask questions or share Firepad apps you're building with the community